# Given $m$ $n$-dimensional vectors, how to create a vector perpendicular to all of them?

Tags: linear, matrix, linear-algebra

Given $m$ vectors, $x_1$, $x_2$, ... $x_m$ with all $x_i \,\, \epsilon \,\, \mathcal{R}^n$, $i=1,2... m$ and $m < n$.

How to sample a vector $x_{m+1}$ perpendicular to all the vectors $x_1$, $x_2$, ... $x_m$.

Comment: [Gram–Schmidt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) them.

Comment: Equivalently, sample $x$ with any distribution you like, regress that on $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_m,$ and take the residual.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to say more about the distribution you wish to sample from, as well as whether you need this process to be computationally efficient and numerically stable. If you're just looking to generate any vector from the orthogonal complement, check out [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1232747/348855) from Math SE.